# Скрыть комментарии в VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как можно скрыть/показать комментрарии к коде? Не удалить, а именно спрятать на время.

Answer (score 2):

Есть встроенная возможность сворачивать блоки многострочных комментариев. Но это работает только с несколькими видами знаков комментариев. Например, многострочные комментарии при использовании `//` или `/* */` символов.

Чтобы свернуть <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>, или:

1. Открыть `Command Palette`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Ввести `Fold All Blocks Comment`

Чтобы развернуть <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, или:

1. Открыть `Command Palette`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Ввести `Unfold All`

Для python кода, данная возможность не работает.

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, это расширение сможет вам помочь: [HideShow](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=3dGrabber.HideShowComments)

Comment: Это расширение для Visual Studio. В Visual Studio Code не работает.